# "Package python is not installed" but it is

Tags: python, dpkg

When trying:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i python-numpy_1.13.3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-numpy:
 python-numpy depends on python (>= 2.7~); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-numpy depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-numpy depends on python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~); however:
 python-numpy depends on python:any (<< 2.8); however:
```

In same directory doing:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

How to solve dpkg error?

OS is Ubuntu18.04 LTS & I downloaded the releavnt numpy version.

Machine is not connected to internet.

Comment: You should not install packages with such low-level tool as `dpkg`. Use normal tools such as APT - try `sudo apt-get install python python-numpy`. Also please add output of `which python` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dpkg error is a-bit misleading, what is missing isn't python but python-dev. Install python-dev with all it's dependencies.

Comment: I tried to install Mendeley Desktop for Linux (Kubuntu 20.10) and I incurred in this error ... you were absolutely right! Installing python-dev solved the problem, although it really installed `python2.7-dev` and `python-is-python2`, so now my `python` command points to `python2` instead of `python3`. If I install `python-is-python3` mendeley no longer works

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this code for dependency Problems
`sudo apt-get install -f`

This may solve Your problem if the dependent .deb files are in the Linux repository